# CSS / HTML: centering absolute element in browser window regardles of parent position (parent also absolute)

Tags: html, css

Have a problem centering an element (div, but thats beside the point) in the browser window horizontally. Have no problem positioning it compared to its parent element, but want it to break free from this HORIZONTALLY - but still keep its relation to it vertically. Maybe I'm asking too much? :-) I can do it with position:fixed, but then the element freezes in one position in the browser regardles...

```
 #parent li {
    display:inline;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding: 12px 10px 4px 10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    height:28px;
    border:none;

    }
.child {
    margin:16px 0px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    z-index: 100;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:left;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
    border-top:none;
    line-height:14px;
}
```

I can also ask in another way: this is what I want horizontally:

```
.child { 
margin:16px 0px 0px 0px; 
float:left; 
z-index: 100;
left: calc(50% - 400px); 
left: -moz-calc(50% - 400px); 
left: -webkit-calc(50% - 400px); 
position:fixed; 
top:inherit; 
text-align:left; 
padding:0; 
border:1px solid #BBBBBB; 
border-top:none; 
line-height:14px;
}
```

that leaves it in the middle regardles of the parent. Great. BUT - when you scroll down on the page, if the child is visible, it stays put, whereas the rest of the content scrolls. And if you have scrolled a bit so the parent is not in its original position from the top, the child will not align with the parent but appear from top where the parent originally was, pixel wise... which is not optimal... :-/

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OLfFd.png ... that is what I want to accomplice...

Comment: I can also ask in another way: this is what I want horizontally:

Comment: .child {
margin:16px 0px 0px 0px;
float:left;
z-index: 100;left: calc(50% - 400px);
left: -moz-calc(50% - 400px);
left: -webkit-calc(50% - 400px);
position:fixed;
top:inherit;
text-align:left;
padding:0;
border:1px solid #BBBBBB;
border-top:none;
line-height:14px;

Comment: that leaves it in the middle regardles of the parent. Great. BUT - when you scroll down on the page, if the child is visible, it stays put, whereas the rest of the content scrolls. And if you have scrolled a bit so the parent is not in its original position from the top, the child will not align with the parent but appear from top where the parent originally was, pixel wise... which is not optimal... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Give some (top,bottom) property to your position in div.

```
#parent li {

position:relative;
top:50px;
left:50px;
}

.child {

position:relative;
top:50px;
left:50px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but how would this center the child in the browser, free of the parent?

Comment: if you want only the chlid to be centered then you can use .child class i mentioned above and adjust top and left properties according to your requirements.

Comment: In my experience that would not break it free from the parent (IE would place it relative to the parent, not to the browser window - have tried almost anything, only position:fixed worked, but that broke the relation to it vertically)...

Comment: sorry IE not meaning Internet Explorer but ie. ;-)

Comment: sorry, maybe I'm missing something ... dont see any fix/change?