# In LESS, is it possible to access the third number of an input variable?

Tags: css, less

I am reading the first example on LESS page

```
 @base: #f938ab;

.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: @style @c;
  -moz-box-shadow:    @style @c;
}
.box-shadow(@style, @alpha: 50%) when (isnumber(@alpha)) {
  .box-shadow(@style, rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha));
}
.box { 
  color: saturate(@base, 5%);
  border-color: lighten(@base, 30%);
  div { .box-shadow(0 0 5px, 30%) }
}
```

Above code will generate something like

```
box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

For @style variable, what if I want to use box-shadow: 0 0 5px and 0 0 (5+5)px, without having another @style2 as variable input.

**Is there anything like a indexAt for @style in LESS? To do something like
@style.at(3)+5**

Expected Output:

```
.test {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Manually (but must all be the same output)

Using just your current mixin code, you can get your addition this way:

**LESS**

```
.test {.box-shadow(0 0 unit(5+5, px), 30%)}
```

Produces:

**CSS Output**

```
.test {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

### Automatically with LESS 1.3.2+ (Messy and Difficult)

I've modified the mixin to do some javascript evaluation and get what you want. However, I am not a regular expression expert, nor technically a javascript expert (just know enough to get around), so there may be a more concise way to do what I am doing and also a more general use way of doing it. In my solution here, it *requires* that you give it a three property `@style` string and that the last one be given in a `px` value (so it is not very flexible, but meets your exact specifications fo the question here). Obviously, the LESS 1.4.0 code below is better than this, but until that is out of beta, some (perhaps you) might need something more like the follow:

**LESS**

```
.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  @firstTwoParams: ~`(function() {
    var makeArray = "@{style}".replace(/^\[/,'').replace(/\]$/,'').split(',');
    return (makeArray[0]+makeArray[1]);
  })()`;
  @thirdParam: unit(~`(function() {
    var makeArray = "@{style}".replace(/^\[/,'').replace(/\]$/,'').split(',');
    return makeArray[2];
  })()`, px);
  @resetStyle: @firstTwoParams (@thirdParam+5);
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: @resetStyle @c;
  -moz-box-shadow:    @style @c;
}
```

**CSS Output** is the same as the LESS 1.4.0 code answer below.

### Automatically with LESS 1.4.0 (Clean and Easy)

**Edited based on commented desired output**

In the latest version (currently beta, 1.4.0) of LESS, you could use the `extract` function to access the third member and then automatically have something set up to add to it. Here is an example of a reworked mixin (it would use the exact same call as you currently have):

```
.box-shadow(@style, @c) when (iscolor(@c)) {
  @resetStyle: extract(@style,1) extract(@style,2) (extract(@style,3)+5);
  box-shadow:         @style @c;
  -webkit-box-shadow: @resetStyle @c;
  -moz-box-shadow:    @style @c;
}
```

So your `.box div` code that calls it would produce this:

```
.box div {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

It has added `5px` to your `5px` because of the constant set in the `@resetStyle` variable in the new mixin.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it right, I want the output to be like.test {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

Comment: @ttback: true, you did not mention you wanted to vary it within the mixin for different calls. However, my "automatic" update for LESS 1.4.0 can be made to do that, just set the `webkit` version to the `@resetStyle` and the other two to `@style` (but of course, you need to be on the beta version of LESS to do that).

Comment: @ttback: I updated for a messy solution to get what you need in LESS 1.3.2+ versions. Still best once 1.4.0 is running.

Comment: I see. I ended up realizing that there is a math relationship between the default size and the changed size, so I just set one variable and used Math. But this resetStyle way seems to be more powerful than that. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry, this is a bit rude, maybe, but ScottS - saw your answer to another question and just know/hope that you might have the golden solution for me ... :-) So ScottS ... could I maybe lead you in the direction of my question: [CSS / HTML: centering absolute element in browser window regardles of parent position (parent also absolute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803850/css-html-centering-absolute-element-in-browser-window-regardles-of-parent-pos) ... have an example of the problem here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nhd8y/4/ ...

```
#megamenuShops li:hover .dropdown_1column_shop {

    left: calc(50% - 400px);
    left: -moz-calc(50% - 400px);
  left: -webkit-calc(50% - 400px);
    position:fixed;

  top:inherit;
}
```

the div that appears on onmouseover stays in viewport (because of fixed position) when scrolling down - it should stay with the parent menu block. But if I do this I can't get the div centered in the browser window horizontally :-/

And last but not least ... many apologies to ttback for using your question to try to get the attention of ScottS ... hope you will forgive me ...